# Slicing un lista en python

Tags: python

Encontré este ejercicio y no entiendo por que el resultado es: ['a'].

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
letters[1:] = []
print(letters)
```

**Resultado:**

```
['a']
```

Si el indice 0 es: 'a'. El indice 1 es: 'b', no debería el resultado ser:

```
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Agradeceré si alguien me puede aclarar que pasa aquí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando haces `letters[1:]` efectivamente estás seleccionando todos los componentes de una lista desde el 1 en adelante (es decir, todos menos el primero) y estás en lo correcto en suponer que los elementos seleccionados son `['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']`.

Pero fíjate que en este caso el slice se está usando **al lado izquierdo de una asignación**:

```
letters[1:] = []
```

Es decir, en las posiciones elegidas por el slice, estás metiendo el valor `[]`. Estás **reemplazando** lo que había en ese slice por una lista vacía.

Es por eso que al final sólo queda el primer elemento. Los restantes han sido sustituídos por la lista vacía. Es una forma rápida de borrarlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mas alla de la pregunta, por pura curiosidad. No seria mejor y mas claro usar del lista[1:]?

Comment: @eduardotejeda si la respuesta de Abulafia te sirvio puedes elegirla como la mejor como forma de agradecimiento c: (es decir, apretar la tildecita a la izquierda de la respuesta)

Comment: @DanteS. Para el caso de eliminar los elementos estoy de acuerdo en que un `del` es mucho más claro y el resultado será el mismo. Pero la asignación a slices tiene otros usos como reemplazar una serie de elementos de un array por otros (que pueden ser menos), por ejemplo: `lista[1:] = ['x']` daría como resultado `['a', 'x']` y es más corto (no sé si más legible) que `del lista[1:]; lista.append('x')`

Comment: Entiendo! Gracias c: